# Can annotation method accept arguments?

Tags: java, annotations

I am writing annotations rarely but it widly used in java frameworks.

I have investigate annotation source and I have a question

All annotation method sources what I have seen doesn't accept arguments.

example(from spring-mvc):

```
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, METHOD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Resource {
    /**
     * The JNDI name of the resource.  For field annotations,
     * the default is the field name.  For method annotations,
     * the default is the JavaBeans property name corresponding
     * to the method.  For class annotations, there is no default
     * and this must be specified.
     */
    String name() default "";

    /**
     * The name of the resource that the reference points to. It can
     * link to any compatible resource using the global JNDI names.
     *
     * @since Common Annotations 1.1
     */

    String lookup() default "";

    /**
     * The Java type of the resource.  For field annotations,
     * the default is the type of the field.  For method annotations,
     * the default is the type of the JavaBeans property.
     * For class annotations, there is no default and this must be
     * specified.
     */
    Class<?> type() default java.lang.Object.class;

    /**
     * The two possible authentication types for a resource.
     */
    enum AuthenticationType {
            CONTAINER,
            APPLICATION
    }

    /**
     * The authentication type to use for this resource.
     * This may be specified for resources representing a
     * connection factory of any supported type, and must
     * not be specified for resources of other types.
     */
    AuthenticationType authenticationType() default AuthenticationType.CONTAINER;

    /**
     * Indicates whether this resource can be shared between
     * this component and other components.
     * This may be specified for resources representing a
     * connection factory of any supported type, and must
     * not be specified for resources of other types.
     */
    boolean shareable() default true;

    /**
     * A product specific name that this resource should be mapped to.
     * The name of this resource, as defined by the <code>name</code>
     * element or defaulted, is a name that is local to the application
     * component using the resource.  (It's a name in the JNDI
     * <code>java:comp/env</code> namespace.)  Many application servers
     * provide a way to map these local names to names of resources
     * known to the application server.  This mapped name is often a
     * <i>global</i> JNDI name, but may be a name of any form. <p>
     *
     * Application servers are not required to support any particular
     * form or type of mapped name, nor the ability to use mapped names.
     * The mapped name is product-dependent and often installation-dependent.
     * No use of a mapped name is portable.
     */
    String mappedName() default "";

    /**
     * Description of this resource.  The description is expected
     * to be in the default language of the system on which the
     * application is deployed.  The description can be presented
     * to the Deployer to help in choosing the correct resource.
     */
    String description() default "";
}
```

can annotation method accepts arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: no

Annotations in fact do not have methods. They have attributes (with optional default values), which look syntactically similar to methods.

Comment: What about long answer?

Comment: you may add further attributes which are semantically similar to params. I mean something like @MyAnnotation(myMethodLikeAttribute="maybeNotStringButBoolean", myParamLikeAttribute1="paramVal1" ,myParamLikeAttribute2="paramVal2")